# Type of class instance

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have the following code, running on Python 3.9.2, that I cannot make work.

```
from__future__ import annotations

class P():
    def __eq__(self:P, comparand:P) -> bool:
        return false
```

Mypy complains that

```
Argument 1 of "__eq__" is incompatible with supertype "object";
supertype defines the argument types as "object"
```

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I assume that there are syntax errors but I cannot determine what they are.

Comment: Post the real code you tested, not code that may or may not resemble it.

Comment: "Any suggestions on how this can be done?" Can you clarify what "this" is? Be aware that equality is defined across *all* types. So ``a == b`` should return a result for all ``a``, ``b``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the **eq** method is for any object, without :P it would work.
You might check the type of the argument using is isinstance in your code (if necessary).

```
from__future__ import annotations

class P():
    def __eq__(self, comparand) -> bool:
        return false
```

Answer (score 1):

`__eq__` should be able to compare your instance against any type of object. You are overriding the `__eq__` method of the object class, and you are defining your `__eq__` with a different argument type for Argument 1.

Fix it by changing Argument 1 to object:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class P():
    def __eq__(self:P, comparand) -> bool:
        return False
```